# How I can read List from last item to the first Item

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to flip list to be able to read that list from last item to first 
ex : list[a,b,c,d]
I want to get that list as [d,c,b,a];
anyone have Idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reversed`.

An example,

```
List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c"];
list = list.reversed.toList();
print(list); // Result [c, b, a]
```

---

Document of `reversed`

```
/**
* Returns an [Iterable] of the objects in this list in reverse order.
*/
Iterable<E> get reversed;
```